# Disappearing horses

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've recently noticed this glitch that every once in a while, my horse disappears when I climb off it. I am playing 1.14 Minecraft java. Usually, it reappears when I restart the world. The computer I am playing on isn't very powerful, but I also saw it happen on another computer, which is slightly more powerful than mine. So please tell me if it's just me who loses my horses (which is very unlikely), a glitch, or is it just my computer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a visual issue. I don't currently know the report number, but closing+reopening the world/leaving+rejoining the server is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I suppose that's what I'll have to do, it's happening less and less though.